# Google auth2 facebook login not working

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1+. I have used google auth2 for facebook login. It was working fine before. But now it is showing the exception "Required option not passed: access_token" while trying to access the token. Below code generates the exception.

```
$token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
'code' => $code
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem caused by a change in Facebook. Facebook deprecated their Graph API version 2.2. I got the answer from here. https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=349917&parent=1412197

Answer (score 1):

The plugin stopped working on 27th March 2017 as Facebook closed the API 2.2. The latest version of this plugin have been updated to support Facebook 2.8 API.

Please refer this : https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_googleoauth2
Hope this helps.